# Popup window must triggered only app foreground in Android

Tags: android, firebase, popup, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase Notification service. When I send notification from Firebase.

I don't want to save this information. I mean that Notification only appear when User is online in MainActivity. If user run another activity , he see no notification but when user comes MainActiviy Notification must come.

```
public class NotificationService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String getBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    // Uygulama suan kullanılıyorsa.
    if (isAppForground(getApplicationContext())){
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                .putExtra("data",getBody)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }else{

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Fixtown")
                .setContentText(getBody)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        manager.notify(123, notification);
    }

}

public boolean isAppForground(Context mContext) {

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you see. So which flag must put to in .setFlags() and How to catch this notification only in MainActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to let your app handle the push notification and not the system, you would want to use Data Message instead of Notification Message.
Please refer to:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

I would suggest using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to achieve this.

In order to control the notification pop up according to which activity is on foreground, you will need to register at onResume() and unregister at onPause().

In your app level build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Create a Java class and name it NotificationEvent:

```
public class NotificationEvent {
    private String body;

    public NotificationEvent(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

In your NotificationService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived");
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        // do nothing if Notification message is received
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotificationEvent(body));
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(NotificationEvent event) {
    // do something to the notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Fixtown")
            .setContentText(event.getBody())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    manager.notify(123, notification);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Noel